# Read below JSON data and fetch status name

Tags: java, json

**I want to get the name of the status from JSON data.**
{
"expand": "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
"id": "3876562",
"self": "https://jira2.abc.com/rest/api/2/issue/3876562",
"key": "DEVACDMY-35289",
"fields": {
"status": {
"self": "https://jira2.abc.com/rest/api/2/status/3",
"description": "",
"iconUrl": "https://jira2.abc.com/images/icons/statuses/inprogress.png",
"name": "In Progress",
"id": "3",
"statusCategory": {
"self": "https://jira2.abc.com/rest/api/2/statuscategory/4",
"id": 4,
"key": "indeterminate",
"colorName": "yellow",
"name": "In Progress"
}
}
}
}
I try this but it doesn't work.

```
Map address = ((Map)jo.get("fields"));
          
        // iterating address Map
        Iterator<Map.Entry> itr1 = address.entrySet().iterator();

        while (itr1.hasNext()) {
 Map.Entry pair = itr1.next(); 
Map status=((Map)jo.get(pair.key); 
Iterator<Map.Entry> itr2 =status.entrySet().iterator(); while(itr2.hasNext())
{
itr1=((Map)itr2.next()).entrySet().iterator();
while(itr1.hasNext())
{
Map.Entry pair=itr1.next();
System.out.println(pair.getKey()+":"+pair.getValue());
}}
```

Comment: ok. and what is your actual question?

Comment: I edited the question maybe it clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the json, it is not an array, it is simply a JsonObject and to get the string of the status name you need to traverse the same way.

To get the status name there is a hierarchy that you need to follow

> JSONObject -->  **fields***(this is again a JSONObject)* --> **status***(this is
> again a JSON object)* -> **name** *(this is string)*

Look at the following code

```
String str = "{\n" +
                "    \"expand\": \"renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations\",\n" +
                "    \"id\": \"3876562\",\n" +
                "    \"self\": \"https://jira2.abc.com/rest/api/2/issue/3876562\",\n" +
                "    \"key\": \"DEVACDMY-35289\",\n" +
                "    \"fields\": {\n" +
                "        \"status\": {\n" +
                "            \"self\": \"https://jira2.abc.com/rest/api/2/status/3\",\n" +
                "            \"description\": \"\",\n" +
                "            \"iconUrl\": \"https://jira2.abc.com/images/icons/statuses/inprogress.png\",\n" +
                "            \"name\": \"In Progress\",\n" +
                "            \"id\": \"3\",\n" +
                "            \"statusCategory\": {\n" +
                "                \"self\": \"https://jira2.abc.com/rest/api/2/statuscategory/4\",\n" +
                "                \"id\": 4,\n" +
                "                \"key\": \"indeterminate\",\n" +
                "                \"colorName\": \"yellow\",\n" +
                "                \"name\": \"In Progress\"\n" +
                "            }\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "}";
        JSONObject jsonarray = new JSONObject(str);
        JSONObject fields = jsonarray.getJSONObject("fields");
        JSONObject status = fields.getJSONObject("status");
        String name = status.getString("name");
        System.out.println("fields : " + fields);
        System.out.println("status : " + status);
        System.out.println("name: " + name);
```

output :-

```
fields : {"status":{"name":"In Progress","self":"https://jira2.abc.com/rest/api/2/status/3","description":"","iconUrl":"https://jira2.abc.com/images/icons/statuses/inprogress.png","id":"3","statusCategory":{"colorName":"yellow","name":"In Progress","self":"https://jira2.abc.com/rest/api/2/statuscategory/4","id":4,"key":"indeterminate"}}}
status : {"name":"In Progress","self":"https://jira2.abc.com/rest/api/2/status/3","description":"","iconUrl":"https://jira2.abc.com/images/icons/statuses/inprogress.png","id":"3","statusCategory":{"colorName":"yellow","name":"In Progress","self":"https://jira2.abc.com/rest/api/2/statuscategory/4","id":4,"key":"indeterminate"}}
name: In Progress
```